# Adapt V-brakes bicycle to disk brakes

Tags: disc-brake

I've been thinking in changing my v-brakes to disc brakes.
Now that my rear v-brake can't brake anymore I think that it is time change it.
I've already seen [this article](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/16362/how-do-i-know-whether-my-bike-can-use-disk-brakes). My frame is prepared for disc and, as I don't want to change my brake lever, I'll go with mechanical brakes (does [this](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/New-Avid-BB7-Mountain-Mechanical-Disc-Brake-Front-Rear-Caliper-HS1-160mm-Rotor-/191078659421?pt=UK_sportsleisure_cycling_bikeparts_SR&var=&hash=item2c7d2cf55d) look ok?);

The only problem is the rear wheel hub that has not the six holes for the disk. Is it ok if I just change the rear wheel hub and keep the front one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically, the front brake is more important if not as important as the rear brake, so you'd be better off swapping to a front disc (plus, if you are buying genuine Avid BB7's, they're sold as a front and rear kit IIRC). If you don't have a disc ready wheelset, you just need to get a disc ready wheel set (the front wheel is relatively cheap compared to a rear wheel) - I don't really see the point of reusing a rim in this case, since it will likely not be cost effective [and I never approve of reusing spokes].

Also, check the condition of the levers and use new cables + cable housing when replacing the brake.

Good luck!

P.S. It is spelled "brake", not "break".

(Note that this will all be significant in cost relative to putting on a new V-brake (Avid Single Digit 5's are under 20 dollars a piece. If you put in a new FR-5 lever and new cable housing and cable, you'll still be under 40 dollars - this may be a better option if you were satisfied with v-brake performance [obviously, you can opt for better V-brakes, pads and levers for not much more, but the point still stands that a good V-brake is significantly cheaper than a disc conversion, and decent levers really aren't that expensive]. Make sure this replacement is economical on the bike you're using - in some cases, with cheaper disc-ready frames, you're actually better off selling the current bike and getting something with disc brakes on it already!)

Comment: +1: Top quality properly maintained V brakes out perform cheap disks in 99% of situations and will be within a hairs breath of BB7's. IMHO Its just not worth the cost and effort.