# Apollo Highway Brake Discs ?

Tags: folding-bicycle

can i add custom disc Brakes to the front at all ?

Bike info here
http://www.thebikelist.co.uk/apollo/highway-700c-trekking-hybrid-bike-2010

Thanks

Comment: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/20766/adapt-v-brakes-bicycle-to-disk-brakes and http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/16362/how-do-i-know-whether-my-bike-can-use-disk-brakes should help

Answer (score 4):

You could put a disc fork on, but by the time you bought the disc fork and a decent front disc brake, it would cost half as much as that bike is worth new. You would also need a disc-ready wheel in the front. This would probalby bring the cost to 3/4ths of the cost of the bike.

You're better off installing good rim brakes (which are essentially on par with non-high end cable operated disc brakes), or selling the bike and buying one which has disc brakes already on it.