# Disc brakes 29 inch bike

Tags: brakes

I have a 2018 se big flyer and it has regular v brakes i was wondering if I could upgrade to disc brakes in front and back. I have look other places but no has anything to convert it.

Comment: Other questions on disk brake conversion https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/16362/how-do-i-know-whether-my-bike-can-use-disk-brakes ,

Answer (score 3):

If this is the bike at http://www.sebikes.com/bikes/cat/rad-series/big-flyer-29

Then it can’t be done. The frame and fork lacks mount points for disc brake callipers.

Comment: If it's that bike... seriously, who makes a bike with only a rear brake? That's possibly the dumbest design decision I've ever seen.

Comment: It's for people who want to do barspins and either don't understand braking or can't afford gyro.

Comment: I think it is not unusual for BMX bikes to have only rear brakes or none at all. There seems to be a demand for BMX bikes with large wheels, eg for people who are too large for typical BMX bikes, or those who rather cruise than do tricks. The bike mentioned in the question appears to be such a bike.